# Kendo treeview expands on initialization not working

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm trying to expand Kendo treeview all nodes on initialization.
But is not working. Here are solutions I have referenced:
1.http://dojo.telerik.com/UqOxa/2
2.http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-you-default-a-treeview-to-expanded-on-initialization

My source code:
html:

```
<div id="kendoTreeViewSelector"
 kendo-tree-view="tree"
 k-data-source="treeData"
 k-on-change="selectedItem = dataItem"                     
 k-on-data-bound="onDataBound"
 ng-click="kendoTreeViewToggle($event)">
 <span k-template>
    {{dataItem.text}}
 </span>
</div>
```

Angular controller:

```
ServiceMenusRepository.getMenus(data.EmployeeNO, 2, selectType, SystemSN,
                function (data) {
                if (data.data) {
                    $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                        data: data.data,

                    });

                    $scope.subMenuItems = data.data;

                    $scope.onDataBound = function (e) {

                        setTimeout(function () {

                            $scope.tree.expand(".k-item");;
                        });
                    }

                    $scope.kendoTreeViewToggle = function (e) {
                        var target = $(e.target);
                        var toggleIcon = target.closest(".k-icon");
                        if (!toggleIcon.length) {
                            this.tree.toggle(target.closest(".k-item"));
                        }
                    };
                    $timeout(function () {
                        initMenu();

                        menu2q.resolve();
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    menu2q.resolve();
                }
            }, menuq.reject);
```

By the way, I'm using Kendo UI v2015.1.429.
Is there any suggestion for this problem?
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dataBound event of the TreeView, try:

```
e.sender.expand(".k-item");
```

It's from the demo at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/treeview-integration. I just used it yesterday and my tree is all expanded.

You can also try adding an expanded: true field to the items in data.data as this demo does when it sets the data for its HierarchicalDataSource: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/filter-treeview-in-dialog

Comment: I added expanded: true in the data array, it works!!  Thanks for your help!